# Matlab code dimension error of k-means algorithm

Tags: matlab, k-means

Use K_mean algorithm to cluster data data. The cluster center is IRS and the number of clusters is IRS_num. However, sometimes an error will be reported.

```
function [index_cluster,cluster] = kmeans_func(data,cluster_num,IRS)
%% 原理推导Kmeans聚类算法
[m,n]=size(data);
cluster=IRS;%从m个点中随机选择cluster_num个点作为初始聚类中心点
epoch_max=1000;%最大次数
therad_lim=0.001;%中心变化阈值
epoch_num=0;
while(epoch_num<epoch_max)
    epoch_num=epoch_num+1;
    % distance1存储每个点到各聚类中心的欧氏距离
    for i=1:cluster_num
        distance=(data-repmat(cluster(i,:),m,1)).^2;
        distance1(:,i)=sqrt(sum(distance'));
    end
    [~,index_cluster]=min(distance1');%index_cluster取值范围1~cluster_num
    % cluster_new存储新的聚类中心
    for j=1:cluster_num
        cluster_new(j,:)=mean(data(find(index_cluster==j),:));
    end

    %如果新的聚类中心和上一轮的聚类中心距离和大于therad_lim，更新聚类中心，否则算法结束
    if (sqrt(sum((cluster_new-cluster).^2))>therad_lim)
        cluster=cluster_new;
    else
        break;
    end
end
end
```

```
赋值具有的非单一 rhs 维度多于非单一下标数

出错
kmeans_func
(line 18)
        cluster_new(j,:)=mean(data(find(index_cluster==j),:));
```

There may be a problem with the code assignment dimension. I don’t know how to modify it. I hope to get help.

Comment: You never create `cluster_new`, so it is likely to have the wrong size.